# How to set SetLocal info using C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to change the Language for unicode program in Control Tab.Only information I got was to use SetLocaleInfo Win32 method.Can anyone please give me some code to use SetLocaleInfo method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetLocaleInfo.html) to call that method.

Comment: Daneil can you please provide me some example that will really be very helpful

Comment: @A.J, follow Daniel's link. It shows how to declare the P/Invoke function. As for examples, you already found examples of SetLocaleInfo, didn't you? That's how you decided it was what you needed. They should be easy to translate to C#. If you have trouble, you'll need to give us more specifics.

Comment: Thanks Daneil but still after lot of searching I am not able to find some exxamples on net.